# Could someone summarize the iOS Developer Program for a non-English speaker?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am not a native English speaker, so I have some problems understanding the documentation for the iOS Developer Program.  I have paid 99 dollars to be a developer but I don't understand all the certificates, provisioning profiles etc.

Could anybody please tell me what the different things I download are and why I do it in a "easier" language? Would be much appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Tried using Google translate?  While you may not be able to add a URL to translate it, you might be able to get by with pasting in text from the page.

Comment: @Wayne : I will try that! Did not think of it, thanks!

Comment: If you can't grok it right away, don't despair. English is my first language and provisioning/certification is still like a black art.

Comment: I feel the same way as @Mark, provisioning is one of the hardest things in iOS programming..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try:
Once you are registered you can download SDKs (XCode 4,...) develop Apps and test it on the included iPhone Simulator. 
Every iOS App must be tested on the available Devices, such as (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch, ...), to check that your code works. 
To get your App on your Device you need the Provisioning Profile. 
Check https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action for Documentations and Informations.

When you finished developing your App and you want to make your App available on the App Store you then will have to create a Distribution profile.

The certificate stuff is needed, because your Apps are signed with them.

I am not a professional Developer, but I got after reading the Docus and Informations provided by Apple.

Hope that helps. 
Yours Raphael